# How to capture and recreate complete Django program state?

Tags: python, django, debugging

When a user experiences an exception -- or sees a bug and reports it -- it would be very helpful to be able to capture and recreate their exact program state for debugging purposes.

Imagine a user runs into a problem and you are able to recreate and debug it -- i.e. drop into a Werkzeug-style interactive trace or ipdb prompt on your development machine with a copy of the database made at that moment.

It seems easy enough to dump a copy of the database at exception time or on demand. But how to recreate program state and get into the Werkzeug trace or ipdb prompt? Are there any tools or Django apps out there that do something like this?

Comment: Have you tried a raven + sentry setup, it has a replay request feature. It doesn't capture db state but you could quite easily write your own handler.

Comment: If you just want to roll your own approach to this, you can use the `pickle` module to dump python objects into files in your exception handler.

Comment: I would take a look at https://rollbar.com/features/replays/ they have a reply system.